# How can I push the changes as the master branch (default)?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, intellij-idea

I linked my project with Github 4 months ago and I today deleted my project unintentionally so I reinstall the last commit from Github and open it in Android Studio but when I make any changes I cannot push it to Github as a master branch but if I push it as different branch it is worked, How can I push the changes as the master branch (default)?

[image]

**Show details in console**

```
12:48:16.974: [Project] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master --set-upstream
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/.../...'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
To https://github.com/.../...
!   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [rejected] (fetch first)
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
Done
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Find out *why* the push was rejected (see the label "Show details in console" in your image).

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo I know what is the problem but I don't know how can I solve it, The problem is that Github thinks I'm not the owner of the project so it permits me to create my branch only but how can I tell Github I'm the project owner even I can update master branch? I saw the link before but does not work with me.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I saw the link before but does not work with me.

Comment: @torek Check the update

Answer (score 2):

You can try git push from console it will either work without issue or it will tell you what exact problem is and the alternate command (something like `git push --set-upstream`) to fix it.

PS try to learn git basics from any place (youtube / pluralsight) etc and try to use command line as much as you can I have switched to command line for past 2 years and my git understanding is quite improved plus it helps avoid any pesky issues with studio.

**Edit** - As pointed by the update in question you need to pull the lastest changes by `git pull` before you can push.

Answer (score 1):

Select master as your remote branch in Android Studio>Git>Branches>Remote Branches

Comment: I selected the master branch already, Check the image above

Comment: There might be two reasons: 1. You have the wrong remote URL set. 2. Your PC's ssh key expired or didn't add in your git setting ssh list.

Comment: I know what is the problem but I don't know how can I solve it, The problem is that Github thinks I'm not the owner of the project so it permits me to create my branch only but how can I tell Github I'm the project owner even I can update master branch?